# How to loop over an array and when we reach the end start over?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of urls that I want to do pass to a function, I'll be using a cron job to pass only 2 of them every 10 minutes, I'm storing the last passed index of this array in a database, the problem is I don't know how to pass the first 2 elements when the last passed element is the last one in the array, let me explain with the code:

```
$sites = array(
    'http://www.example.com/',
    'http://www.example1.com/',
    'http://www.example2.com/',
    'http://www.example3.com/',
    'http://www.example4.com/',
    'http://www.example5.com/'
);

// the number of urls to pass to the function
// Edit: I forgot to say that this number might change later
$sites_to_pass = 2;

// this value is supposed to be stored when we finish processing the urls
$last_passed_index = 2;

// this is the next element's index to slice from
$start_from = $last_passed_index + 1;

// I also want to preserve the keys to keep track of the last passed index
$to_pass = array_slice($sites, $start_from, $sites_to_pass, true);
```

`array_slice()` is working fine, but when the `$last_passed_index` is `4` I only get the last element in the array, and when it's `5` (the last index) I get an empty array.

What I want to do is when it's `4` to get the last element and the first element, and when it's `5` which is the last element's index to get the first 2 elements in the array.

I'm not so good with php, any suggestions what should I do instead of creating a function to check the indexes ?

Comment: You are asking to run it every ten minutes, but also to start over when it's done. What is it exactly that you want it to do?

Comment: @Allendar the script should be checking these urls regularly.

Comment: I think the answers already given can help you Peter. I just want to add that if you're planning to run this script non-stop for some reason, you should be careful. If the PHP process (script) does *never* stop it will keep consuming more and more memory from your server. PHP can't really memory very well. If there is no problem with certain cron jobs still running while another starts, it's not a problem to set the crontab to run every 1 minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One interesting solution is to make use of the [SPL Iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php).  The [InfiniteIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php) is the one to use.

In this example, you start with the last array element and iterate twice:

```
$sites = array(
    'http://www.example0.com/',
    'http://www.example1.com/',
    'http://www.example2.com/',
    'http://www.example3.com/',
    'http://www.example4.com/',
    'http://www.example5.com/'
);

$result = array();
$infinite = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($sites));

// this value is supposed to be stored when we finish processing the urls
$last_passed_index = 5;

// this is the next element's index to slice from
$start_from = $last_passed_index + 1;

foreach (new LimitIterator($infinite, $start_from, 2) as $site) {
    $result[] = $site;
}

var_dump($result);

// output
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "http://www.example0.com/"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "http://www.example1.com/"
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is working great, very nice solution, but can we keep the original keys like the result from `array_slice()` so we can pass it next time ?

Comment: Never mind I found the solution to get the key, in the foreach loop we use `as $key => $site` and store it as `$result[$key] = $site`.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-clever trick: duplicate the URL list with `array_merge` so you have it repeated twice. Then select from that doubled list. That'll let you select slices from the end that overlap the beginning.

```
$start_from = ($last_passed_index + 1) % count($sites_to_pass);
$to_pass    = array_slice(array_merge($sites, $sites), $start_from, $sites_to_pass, true);
```

Adding `% count($sites_to_pass)` makes `$start_from` start back over at 0 once it exceeds the end of the array. This lets you loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

Little dirty, but something like:

```
$to_pass = $start_from == 5 ? array($sites[5], $sites[0]) : array_slice($sites, $start_from, $sites_to_pass, true);
```